# IComparer & Sorting Multiple Levels of ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, filter, listcollectionview

For performance reasons, I am using a `ListCollectionView` with a `CustomSort` sorter rather than multiple `SortDescriptions`.

Using `SortDescriptions`, it is rather easy to sort data by multiple levels, but I am stuck doing the same with the `IComparer`, below.

The aim is to group all `Favorite` (`bool`) at the top, within all favourites, to sort them by `Count` (`int`) and finally by `Name` (`string`).

#### My current `IComparer` implementation:

```
public class CustomSorter : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        var gA = a as MyObj;
        var gB = b as MyObj;

        var favourite = gA.Favorite.CompareTo(gB.Favorite);
        var count = gA.Count.CompareTo(gB.Count);
        var name = gA.Name.CompareTo(gB.Name);

        return favourite != -1 ? favourite : count != -1 ? count : name;
    }
}
```

My rationale was this: if `a` is not greater than `b` in terms of `Favorite`, then check its `Count` and finally `Name`.

Unfortunately, the above `IComparer` implementation does not yield the desired results - the sorting is all over the place.

#### It should look like the following:

```
1. true  100 Z
2. true  50  A
3. true  50  B
4. true  10  A
5. false 100 Z
6. false 50  A
7. false 100 A
8. false 100 B
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget to check for `null` when you're try casting using `as`. You could still get a `NullReferenceException` if the cast is unsuccessful

Comment: Good point!  Are there also cases where this could happen where one can be certain the objects can only be of one specific type? Just so I know for my edification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking 1 out of 3 possibilities into account.

- If A.Favorite is true and B.Favorite is false, you handle it well
- If A.Favorite == B.Favorite, you return 0 instead of looking for Count
- If A.Favorite is false and B.Favorite is true, you're checking for Count instead of returning -1

What you want is something like this:

```
public int Compare(object a, object b)
{
    var gA = a as MyObj;
    var gB = b as MyObj;

    //Handle null values, same references...

    if(gA.Favorite != gB.Favorite) return gA.Favorite.CompareTo(gB.Favorite);

    if(gA.Count != gB.Count) return gA.Count.CompareTo(gB.Count);

    return gA.Name.CompareTo(gB.Name);
}
```

Or writing it like you did:

```
return favourite != 0 ? favourite : count != 0 ? count : name;
```

Comment: Gosh, yes. This is exactly it - I was completely disregarding two of the cases by comparing for `<` rather than equality. Thanks for the logic list highlighting where I was mistaken.